# update UItableviewcell after button tapped for cell

Tags: uitableview

Hello guys i have cells in tableview, but there are two different UIButtons to be assigned to cell. Depend on if the filename those cell indication is there in the sandbox.

i am doing this by following function while creating cell.

```
NSLog(@"%@", filepath);

        if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filepath]) 
        {
            [button setTitle:@"Submit" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [button addTarget:self action:@selector(SubmitData:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        }

        else
        {
            [button setTitle:@"Fetch" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [button addTarget:self action:@selector(FetchData:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        }
```

but the thing is that when i press Fetch button and when FetchData function is called, i fetch the data and save it in the sandbox. So i want to update the button to Submit as now the file is their.

So do i have to put something in FetchData function to update the cell button to Submit,

I tried using [self.tableview reloaddata];

but won't update the cell.

FULL CODE

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *FirstLevelCell= @"FirstLevelCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:FirstLevelCell];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle  reuseIdentifier:FirstLevelCell] autorelease];
        NSDictionary * assignment = [assignments objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        cell.textLabel.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Riding Number is %@", [assignment objectForKey:@"Riding_Number"]];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Poll Number is %@",[assignment objectForKey:@"Poll"]];
        UIImage *buttonUpImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button_up.png"];
        UIImage *buttonDownImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button_down.png"];
        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, (buttonUpImage.size.width)*1.20,
                                  buttonUpImage.size.height);
        [button setBackgroundImage:buttonUpImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button setBackgroundImage:buttonDownImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
          button.tag = [indexPath row];  
        NSString * filepath = [self dataFilePathwithFilename:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%@.plist",[assignment objectForKey:@"Riding_Number"],[assignment objectForKey:@"Poll"]]];


        if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filepath]) 
        {
            [button setTitle:@"Submit" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [button addTarget:self action:@selector(SubmitData:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        }

        else
        {
            [button setTitle:@"Fetch" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [button addTarget:self action:@selector(FetchData:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        }

        cell.accessoryView = button;
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        return cell;
    }

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
```

}

Comment: where exactly did you use this code? you should not use this for cell creation but for cell configuration (what you do after the deque.. if(xx==nil) {..} stuff)

Comment: Hi Martin,I am using this code while configuring the cell I am putting the full code in the main question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set the closing `}` for `if (cell == nil)` right after `cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle  reuseIdentifier:FirstLevelCell] autorelease];`

it says in your comment where you should configure the cell!.
the if-not-nil statement is for **creation** only!! after this block you have to *configure* the cell (set texts, buttons, images, accessoryView, ...). Just remember the cell could be in ANY state.  When a cell leaves the visible area (topmost cell when you scroll down), it will be put in a pool where you grab it out again with dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier and configure it to match the required index path (bottom cell that slides into the screen when you scroll down).

Comment: worked sorry i just realized that bug in my code as i was  not able to reuse my cells